# How to setup local git with local blessed repo - Integration Manager Workflow

Tags: linux, eclipse, git, egit

I need explicit steps for properly setting up git according to [Integration-Manager-Workflow](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Distributed-Git-Distributed-Workflows#Integration-Manager-Workflow) style in a unix environment, from scratch. The catch: It all needs to be done in EGit (so it makes sense to my E-brain), and all the repos are local.

Assuming I have a fresh install of Eclipse w/EGit plugin, what is the best path forward?

In the end, I want to have a project I can clone via git, or import using Eclipse. The blessed repo needs to be at `/path/to/blessed/repo/` while the private workspace could be `/path/to/src/` and the public code being at `/path/to/code/`.

I just want to have a project that I can work on in "private", then "Commit and Push" and have it show up in my "public" location. Then, I want to be able to push this "public" location to the "blessed" location. Then, I want to be able to clone the blessed repo with `git clone /path/to/blessed/repo/` and see all my branches (and maybe a tag or two) in the final clone.

I think I can implement this via the commandline, but I feel like I am reinventing the wheel on this one... Can this structure be easily implemented in EGit, or is it only possible (*or advisable*) from the commandline?

Answer (score 2):

This is what I did, just in case there are others out there who can't just default to GitHub for this kind of setup:

## Setup Git Integration Manager Workflow in Eclipse

Step by step guide for EGit and Eclipse Kepler. Many of the steps are for the “Integration Manager”, which should be:

> A project lead who is also a developer who knows the bigger picture of the project

Based off the command-line syntax from here: [treselle.com/blog/git-integration-manager-workflow/](http://www.treselle.com/blog/git-integration-manager-workflow/)

## Pre-Requisites

1. Eclipse Kepler
2. EGit Pluggin

I did this using Linux, so the file paths will have to be changed if you are working in Windows…

## 1. Setup the Blessed Repository

In *Git perspective > Git Repositories view*:

- `Create a new local Git repository`

[image: t1]

Now, we can see the Repository in the Git perspective:

> blessed_repo.git [NO-HEAD - Bare] - …/code/blessed_repo.git

## 2. Clone Blessed Repo as Integration Repo

In *PyDev > PyDev Package Explorer view*:

- `File > Import...`

[image: t2]

Displays a branch selection screen, showing Source Git Repository is empty (because we have no branches).

[image: t2]

- Right-Click on the project: `Team > Share Project...`

[image: t2]

## 3. Create Master Branch

In *Git perspective > Git Repositories view*:

- `Select` integration_repo [NO-HEAD]
- Show the staging area: `Window > Show View > Git Staging`

At this point, there should be at least 1 file in the **Unstaged Changes (#)** section. If not, start over…

- Select files to stage (at least 1) as ready for commit.
- Right click on the selection: `Add to Git Index`
- (Or drag-drop to Staged Changes)

Now, **Staged Changes (#)** shows files ready to be committed in the integration_repo.

- Add a commit message, maybe similar to: > “Initial project commit”
- And `Commit` the file(s)

Finally, push them back to the blessed repo.

- Expand integration_repo [master]
- Expand Remotes
- Right-click on blessed and `Push`

Eclipse will show a “Push Confirmation” with “master: master [new branch]” which says that both projects now have a master branch. This branch should remain stable at all times.

## 4. Create Developer Public

In *Git perspective > Git Repositories view*:

- `Create a new local Git repository`

[image: t4]

Now, tie it to the integration repository.

In *Git perspective > Git Repositories view*:

- Expand *integration_repo [master] - /…/code/integration_repo/.git*
- Right-click on Remotes > `Create Remote`

[image: t4]

Eclipse shows ‘Nothing to fetch - everything is up to date’.

- Right-click on developer1 > `Push`

Shows “Push Results” with “master: master [new branch]”

## 5. Create Developer Private

**This part could be done by Integration Manager and Developers alike**

In *PyDev > PyDev Package Explorer view*:

- `File > Import...`

[image: t5]

The *sample_project* should now be in the Eclipse workspace. Make sure you aren’t trying to import *sample_project* into a workspace which already has a project with the same name…

## 6. Developer1 add a feature

**This part could be done by Integration Manager and Developers alike**

In *Git perspective > Git Repositories view*:

- Expand *developer1_working*, showing branches
- Right click on Branches, `Switch to > New Branch...`

[image: t6]

In *PyDev > PyDev Package Explorer* view:

- Add a new file, file1.py
- Add some docstring text
- Maybe add a `print('python is #1')`

In *Git perspective > Git Repositories view*:

- Select developer1_working
- Open Git Staging view
- Add file1.py to Staged Changes
- Add a descriptive commit message
- `Commit`
- Expand developer1_working
- Expand Remotes
- Right-click on integration: `Push`

[image: t6]

Eclipse Shows Push Confirmation, “feature1: feature1 [new branch]” Also shows beneath that: sample_project/file1.py. So we know we commited the added new branch, which includes the addition of the file.

## 7. Integrate feature into blessed

Now, the Integration Manager will want to pull in the developer changes, test them, and merge with the master branch of the integration repo. Then, push the changes back to developer1 and blessed.

In *Git perspective > Git Repositories view*:

- Expand integration_repo [master] to show Remotes
- Expand remotes to show developer1
- Right-click on developer1: `Fetch`

Eclipse shows Fetch Results as “feature1: developer1/feature1 [new branch]”. So, we have brought in this new branch.

- Expand integration_repo [master]
- Expand Branches
- Expand Local
- Right-click on master: `Merge...`

[image: t7]

Eclipse will then show the result as a Fast-forward, and New HEAD at the latest commit. So, finally, push to the blessed repo

- Expand integration_repo [master]
- Expand Remotes
- Right-click on blessed: `Push`

## 8. Go get beer

Finally, you now have the following repositories all setup:

[image: t8]

If no-one ever reads this, well what a waste of 24 hours of my life hahaha O.o

Comment: Just wanted to shout out to mention somebody read this. :) Thanks!